# Network analysis of android app like in web browser(e.g. Firebug network)

Tags: android, network-analysis

I am working on android app. My app sends lot of Http post request to external web server receives response. Is there any way to monitor network, xhr setting in android may be with eclipse . Where i can monitor all http requests . If yes , How ?, In that case I need to change the workflow of my app , if third party can able to access post data due to security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Bloodhound comes to mind. You have to connect your phone to the same network as your PC or laptop (system). You can see the requests and data logs on your system.

Comment: I'm myself looking for a standalone android app or windows program that can access the data remotely.